# c comparison problems

Tags: c, sockets

The server code on handling receive data:

```
while (1)
{
    /* RECEIVE DATA */
    bytes_recieved = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
    recv_data[bytes_recieved];

    if (strcmp(recv_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(recv_data , "Q") == 0) {
        send(connected, "disconnected",strlen("disconnected"), 0); 
        fflush(stdout);
        close(connected);
        break;

    } else if(strcmp(recv_data , "lala") == 0) {
        printf("\n RECIEVED DATA = %s " , recv_data);
        send(connected, "showMe",strlen("showMe"), 0);  
        fflush(stdout);

    } else {
        printf("\n RECIEVED DATA = %s " , recv_data);
        send(connected, "Could not find",strlen("Could not find"), 0);  
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    fflush(stdout);

}
```

Client code of sending data:

```
// Sending
printf("Please enter the message: ");
fgets(send_data,1024,stdin); // send_data is the string -> char send_data[1024]

// Receive
bytes_recieved=recv(sock,recv_data,1024,0);
recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
printf("\nRecieved data = %s " , recv_data);
```

But, my result is always:

```
Could not find
```

Even if I sent(from client): q or Q or lala

I checked Cplusplus website, I pretty sure, strcmp return 0 when 2 string are matched. Anyone can help, why it always return "Could not find" message?

EDIT => Frederic:

after add this:

```
printf("recv_data: \"%s\"\n", recv_data)
```

From client I sent: lala

Result:

```
recv_data: "lala
"
```

The other double quote is in second line

Comment: is `recv_data` a std::string? if not this should be tagged as C, not C++

Comment: `recv_data[bytes_recieved];` -- did you mean to zero last+1 byte to use with string functions?

Comment: @Necrolis: Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Did you forget about send() in client?

Comment: @james&@loentar: I did. Print out the string before going into if else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [recv()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html) function only writes bytes to your string, it won't append the [null character terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) necessary to properly end it. It looks like you tried to do that yourself:

```
/* RECEIVE DATA */
bytes_recieved = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
recv_data[bytes_recieved];
```

But that should be:

```
/* RECEIVE DATA */
bytes_recieved = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
```

**EDIT:** The string you're sending ends with a newline character. You probably need to remove it in your server code:

```
/* RECEIVE DATA */
bytes_recieved = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
if (bytes_recieved > 0 && recv_data[bytes_recieved - 1] == '\n') {
    --bytes_recieved;  // Overwrite the newline with the null terminator.
}
recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
```

Comment: I added the '\0', but the result still the same. Always give me "could not find". What else information do u need? The whole server-client? code?

Comment: @origame, can you do a `printf("recv_data: \"%s\"\n", recv_data);` after adding the null terminator and post the results, so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @frederic: I sent from client "lala". Result, as you requested is: "recv_data: "awards
""

Comment: is there anyway to compare string beside strcmp()?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using C strings, in which case:

```
if(recv_data == "q" || recv_data == "Q")
```

should be:

```
if(recv_data[0] == 'q' || recv_data[0] == 'Q')
```

also, there are no checks to see that you actually receive some data(or if there was a socket error!), nor is the receive buffer cleared(using `memset` or nulling the last + 1 char after its filled) before its use, which my lead to problems.

Comment: does it have to do with compiler? I am using linux, using gcc as the compiler. just a wild guess

Comment: @origame: not the compiler, the language, the `==` operator for `char*` will compare pointers, not whats actually in the array, which is why you use `strcmp` or directly index the array for 1 letter tests

Answer (score 0):

I feel the statement

```
recv_data[bytes_recieved];
```

should be

```
recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
```

This will ensure the buffer is null terminated and work for string comparisons